# Creating a job board using WordPress (for free)?

Tags: themes, plugin-recommendation, theme-recommendation

I found several plugins/themes for creating a job board with WordPress, but only one solution which is free (see [here](http://kune.fr/blog/wordpress/wp-jobboard-transform-wordpress-into-a-jobboard/))

Are there any other **free** solutions for doing that?

Comment: Whats so wrong with the one you linked?

Comment: Please explain exactly what features you're looking for and why the one you found won't work.  Otherwise we have no criteria with which to evaluate other possible suggestions.

Comment: Hi Hakre, I didn't say there was something wrong, I simply asked if there are ANY alternatives.

Comment: EAMann - the most basic one - to allow others to add job listing.  That's, for example, doesn't exist in the solution I linked to (but does in the paid versions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Plug-ins

- [Job Listing](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/job-listing/)
- [Job Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/job-manager/)
- [WP Careers](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpcareers/)
- [WP Job Board](http://wpjobboard.net/) - *Premium* (This has a similar name to the one you linked to, but they seem to be completely different systems)

### Themes

- [JobRoller](http://appthemes.com/themes/jobroller/) - *Premium*
- [Job Board](http://templatic.com/cms-themes/job-board) - *Premium*
- [JobPress](http://www.dailywp.com/jobpress-wordpress-theme/) - *Premium*
- [Tapp Jobs](http://press75.com/#tapp-jobs) - *Premium*

As you can see, a lot of available solutions are premium plug-ins or themes.  The pricing seems fairly reasonable ($25-$40 for a good solution), but if you're really strapped with your project budget the free plug-ins might serve as a good base for building your own replacement.

*Once again, though, I have no criteria with which to judge any of these alternatives since you never explained exactly what you were looking for.  All of these options will help you build a job site, but without a better understanding of what you're trying to accomplish, I have no idea which, if any, would be the best route for you.*

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for giving me a rough start. Cheers, T

Answer (score 0):

Another one job board software from Enginethemes: http://www.enginethemes.com/themes/jobengine/ It's really really beautiful and powerful job board. I think you need to check it, demo here: http://demo.enginethemes.com/jobengine/